# BootStrap Mobile CSS Code Not Registering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This may be a stupid question, but I have a website and I'm learning BootStrap. I have styles working correctly on  my browser(even when I shrink them down to mobile view). However if I look at it on the mobile website through my phone, nothing is registering...any ideas?

http://goo.gl/yfhNi - Link for viewing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of details which will hopefully help you get closer to the answer.

In the head, add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and on line 24, close the H4 tag.

See what happens after you make those corrections.

Good luck!

Comment: Great, this worked! One more thing though, when I view it in mobile, it looks to be that it's not picking up padding/margins on the right side of anything...any reason why?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "on the right side of anything"?

Comment: ok so if you view my site in mobile, the text should have a padding on it to the left(sorry no idea why I said right). Well it goes right up against the box in mobile.

Comment: Yea, everything seems to be working in good order. Thanks a ton for your help!